# Will including itinerary along with UK visit visa be helpful

Tags: visas, uk

Should I include itinerary along with printed application form for UK visit visa application.
Secondly should the itinerary contain specifics about my vacation in UK or it should be summarized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to submit a *detailed* itinerary unless the consulate explicitly asks you for it, but you will need to list the activities you intend to undertake while in the UK.

In particular, the application form asks (among other things):

- What do you intend to do in the UK?
- Where will you stay in the UK?

You should list briefly the activities you will be doing (e.g. visiting family, shopping, which tourist sites you want to visit, etc.), and disclose which family member(s) you will stay with, or which hotel(s) you plan to stay in.

Before you complete the visa application, you should review the [application form guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/424265/VAF1-GUIDANCE-NOTES.pdf) to find out how to answer the questions, as well as the [supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) to find out what documents you should submit, and what documents you *should not* submit. For instance, it instructs you to *not* submit hotel and flight bookings.

Comment: I already stated what I plan to do on the form and its submitted,so I'm just asking if I can add letter detailing it more,but since its not mandatory.,I will ignore it.